# Cannot Access Joomla 4.34 Backend - An error has occurred. 0 Call to a member function register() on int

Tags: joomla

After upgrading to Joomla 4.34 I cannot access the backend of my website.

My shared hosting account (Hostmonster) runs MySQL 5.7.23-23, which has limited me to CiviCRM 5.39 and running PHP 7.4.  I've been looking into upgrading my hosting account to one that runs MySQL 5.7.5+ so that I can upgrade to the latest version of CiviCRM and use PHP 8+.

When I tried upgrading to PHP 8, I received this error: Sorry, there was a problem we could not recover from. The server returned a "500 - Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Through file manager I set debug to "true" in the configuration.php file and received the below "Call stack" following the "An error has occurred. 0 Call to a member function register() on int" message.

I asked ChatGPT how to fix it and ChapGPT indicated that it was an issue with CiviCRM, but since I can't get into the backend, I can't try several of the solutions that were suggested.

I'm looking for options to gain access to the administration area of my website again.  Once I do, I will upgrade my hosting account so that I can upgrade CiviCRM.

What do you suggest?  Can I "Turn Off" the CIVICrm Component through file manager?  Would that work?

Thanks,

Mike

---

"An error has occurred. 0 Call to a member function register() on int" message.
Call stack

## Function    Location

1   ()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/ClassLoader.php:82
2   CRM_Extension_ClassLoader->register()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php:618
3   Civi\Core\Container::boot() JROOT/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php:85
4   CRM_Core_Config::singleton()    JROOT/plugins/user/civicrm/civicrm.php:109
5   plgUserCivicrm->civicrmResetNavigation()    JROOT/plugins/user/civicrm/civicrm.php:91
6   plgUserCivicrm->onUserLogin()   JROOT/libraries/src/Plugin/CMSPlugin.php:284
7   Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin->Joomla\CMS\Plugin{closure}()  JROOT/libraries/vendor/joomla/event/src/Dispatcher.php:486
8   Joomla\Event\Dispatcher->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/EventAware.php:111
9   Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication->triggerEvent()   JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:866
10  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->login()  JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:341
11  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->login()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_login/src/Controller/DisplayController.php:82
12  Joomla\Component\Login\Administrator\Controller\DisplayController->login()  JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:678
13  Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute() JROOT/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ComponentDispatcher.php:143
14  Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()   JROOT/administrator/components/com_login/src/Dispatcher/Dispatcher.php:45
15  Joomla\Component\Login\Administrator\Dispatcher\Dispatcher->dispatch()  JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:361
16  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:143
17  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:186
18  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:293
19  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/administrator/includes/app.php:61
20  require_once()  JROOT/administrator/index.php:32

Comment: Just to clarify, the error occurred when you upgraded Joomla, and then got worse when you upgraded PHP, but you haven't recently upgrade Civi right? That's still 5.39?

Comment: Yes.  I can't upgrade beyond 5.39 because my site runs on MySQL 5.7.23-23 and Civi 5.4+ requires MySQL 5.7.5+.  https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/

Comment: I am fairly sure my the issue began after the upgrade to Joomla 4.3.4.  It was several days after upgrading that I attempted to access the backend of my site and ran into this problem.

Comment: Have you cleared CiviCRM caches? Try deleting the contents of the `templates_c` directory.

Comment: That worked! Thank you, Coleman!

Comment: Great. That solution is an oldie but goodie. Kinda like "did you try unplugging it and plugging it back in?" but hey it still works after all these years! Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by clearing caches. Try one or both of the following:

1. On the command line `cd path/to/civicrm` and then `cv flush`.
2. Delete the contents of the `templates_c` directory.